# Como calcular a completude de preenchimento de um banco de dados em R

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a construção de um script em R. Vou fazer uma contextualização para vocês entenderem melhor o questionamento.
Basicamente, estou avaliando a completude de preenchimento dos campos de um banco de dados de saúde.

O banco de dados se constitui de 113 colunas e 173137 linhas, das quais eu preciso saber quantas colunas estão em branco (NA) somando as colunas que contém o número “9” e “09” que são códigos referentes à “ignorado”. Portanto, é o somatório dos “NAs” e “Ignorados” por ano de preenchimento.

Cada linha se refere a um caso de doença (intoxicação por contaminante químico), a linha possui o código do município (ID_MUNICIP), ano (NU_ANO), escolaridade (CS_ESCOL_N), sexo (CS_SEXO), idade (NU_IDADE_N) e outras colunas que trazem informação sobre o caso de contaminação.
A ideia do script é fazer um agrupamento por município (ID_MUNICIP) e por ano (NU_ANO) que mostrasse em porcentagem (%) a “taxa de completude dos campos por município”.

SCRIPTS que tentei escrever mas não funcionam:

```
CONT_MUNI <- DADOS_COMPLETO %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(count(is.na(CS_ESCOL_N)))/length(DADOS_COMPLETO$CS_ESCOL_N) * 100
```

Para ser mais exato, eu preciso avaliar a completude das seguintes colunas:

```
Dt_identificacao  <- select(NU_IDADE_N, CS_SEXO, CS_RACA, CS_ESCOL_N, NU_ANO)
Dt_complementares <- select(ID_OCUPA_N, LOC_EXPO, ZONA_EXP, AGENTE_TOX, VIA_1, CIRCUNSTAN, NU_ANO)
Dt_acompanhamento <- select(TPEXP, HOSPITAL, TPATENDE, CLASSI_FIN, EVOLUCAO, NU_ANO)
```

O resultado final seria uma planilha em excel com 3 abas anteriores (identificação, complementares, acompanhamento) que traria a taxa de completude desses campos em porcentagem, por município, somando os “Ignorados”.
Cortei o banco de dados para ficar menor

Essa foto abaixo é parte do banco, ela mostra as colunas em amarelo que devem ser avaliados

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6heZv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seguinte código talvez resolva o problema. Calcula primeiro as porcentagens para cada grupo de variáveis, sempre com a mesma função e depois escreve a lista de resultados numa planilha Excel.

```
library(dplyr)

find_na <- function(x) {
  na <- is.na(x)
  outros <- x %in% c("09", "99")
  mean(na | outros) * 100
}

Dt_identificacao  <- c("NU_IDADE_N", "CS_SEXO", "CS_RACA", "CS_ESCOL_N")  
Dt_complementares <- c("ID_OCUPA_N", "LOC_EXPO", "ZONA_EXP", "AGENTE_TOX", "VIA_1", "CIRCUNSTAN")
Dt_acompanhamento <- c("TPEXP", "HOSPITAL", "TPATENDE", "CLASSI_FIN", "EVOLUCAO")

CONT_MUNI_identificacao <- DADOS_COMPLETO %>% 
  select(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO, NU_IDADE_N, CS_SEXO, CS_RACA, CS_ESCOL_N) %>%
  group_by(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO) %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(Dt_identificacao), find_na))

CONT_MUNI_complementares <- DADOS_COMPLETO %>% 
  select(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO, ID_OCUPA_N, LOC_EXPO, ZONA_EXP, AGENTE_TOX, VIA_1, CIRCUNSTAN) %>%
  group_by(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO) %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(Dt_identificacao), find_na))

CONT_MUNI_acompanhamento <- DADOS_COMPLETO %>% 
  select(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO, TPEXP, HOSPITAL, TPATENDE, CLASSI_FIN, EVOLUCAO) %>%
  group_by(ID_MUNICIP, NU_ANO) %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(Dt_identificacao), find_na))

df_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^CONT_MUNI_"))
writexl::write_xlsx(df_list, path = "caminho/até/nome_da_planilha.xlsx")
```

Comment: Oi Rui! este script rodou bem e é exatamente o que preciso, entretanto o cálculo está errado, eu precisaria adicionar uma nova coluna com um count de ID_MUNICIP, pra fazer a divisão correta. A ideia seria algo como (SOMA NA+IGN DO MUNICIPIO/TOTAL DE CASOS DO MUNICIPIO*100) Como faço isso? por favor :)

Comment: @sanglx Agora estou perdido, não há *IGN* DO MUNICÍPIO, só ID_MUNICIP. (Se calhar é a mesma coisa mas eu sou português, não sei nada da divisão administrativa do Brasil).

Comment: Bom dia! acabou que consegui fazer aqui! queria te agradecer imensamente pela sua ajuda, você não tem noção do meu desespero hahaha. Você garantiu meu salário nos próximos meses. Editei o código e deu certinho! Você é sensacional cara!!!